# variable won't change Text dynamically in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have my application defined, and I pass `counter` variable as a constructor like below:

```
class AppThreePlusThree extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var game = new Game();
    var counter = 265;
    return new GameRedux(
      counter: counter,
      child: new MaterialApp(
        title: '3 + 3',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new Scaffold(
     ...
     ...
     new Text('$counter'),
     ...
```

I modify the `counter` inside `GameRedux`, and I see variable changes, but it will not effect the Text in the UI, and it stocks on zero why?

Comment: You need to call `setState(() => counter = newValue)` of the component you want to rebuild. If you call `setState()` of a parent descendants will be rebuilt as well. If you call `setState()` on descendants, this will not affect parents - this is the situation you are dealing with.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for your answer, sorry for the embarrassing request, but can you provide little sample code, as an answer so that I can accept you? where should I put setState()?

Answer (score 7):

You have to make your `StatelessWidget` widget to `StatefulWidget` because that is how layout rebuild when state of `counter` variable changed(using `setState()`). Your code should look like below,

```
class AppThreePlusThree extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppThreePlusThreeState createState() => _AppThreePlusThreeState ();
}

class _AppThreePlusThreeState extends State<AppThreePlusThree> {
  var counter = 265;
  var counter2 = 265;

  void changeVariableOnUI() {
    setState(() => counter2 = 22); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var game = new Game();
    // Inside the build method you cannot (no need) use setState but outside the build() to update a variable value on the UI have to use setState
    counter = 265; //I seriously doesnt have any idea how you are going to change or update your counter variable. something like this should work
    return new GameRedux(
      counter: counter,
      child: new MaterialApp(
        title: '3 + 3',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new Scaffold(
     ...
     ...
     Text('$counter'),
     Text('$counter2'),
     InkWell(
       child: Text("Tap here"),
       onTap: changeVariableOnUI,
     ),
     ...
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with creating Stateful Text and passing counter as dynamic variable

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi Let me know if answer helped or not. If not I can delete it.

Comment: Saved me! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Note: `setState()` will not work inside `build()` in flutter new releases. You can simply assign value to that variable without `setState()` there.