# How to show increment of counter in my ui in flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I have declared a variable called ticketCounter that is getting stored in SharedPrefs. This variable is getting incremented and decremented as needed. However I wanted to display this counter on my appBar and want its value to update. Although the value is getting stored in the variable it isn't showing up.

```
  int tickets;
  void fetchTickets() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    tickets = prefs.getInt('ticketRW') ?? 0;
  }
void initState() {
    portraitModeOnly();
    fetchTickets();
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Material(
          child: Scaffold(
                   appBar: AppBar(
              actions: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, right: 14),
                  child: Text(
                   tickets.toString(),//isn't getting updated
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontFamily: "Netflix",
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
               ),
             ),
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [variable won't change Text dynamically in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456755/variable-wont-change-text-dynamically-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [setState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) to update your state.

Change this method:

```
void fetchTickets() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    tickets = prefs.getInt('ticketRW') ?? 0;
}
```

with this:

```
void fetchTickets() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
        tickets = prefs.getInt('ticketRW') ?? 0;
    });
}
```

In Flutter, there are [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and [StatelessWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html).

Stateless widgets have an initial state and it never changes.

Stateful widgets have state objects paired with them. Widgets are UI representations of those state objects. If you have a `counter` variable in a state object, stateful widget will draw the value of `counter`. However, chaning the `counter` variable will not update the UI. You should tell the widget "Hey, I changed your state object, you better check it and update yourself." with setState().

This is an introduction to the state management in Flutter. I suggest you to read further [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt).

Comment: where should I declare the setState method?